# Convert Excel (XLS) to CSV with UTF-8 using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, csv, utf-8

I'm trying to convert excel to csv with UTF - 8 in a Macro. But while converting, the contents are changing to unwanted symbols and text.

Please help me in resolving this.

```
Public Sub convert_UnicodeToUTF8()

   Dim parF1, parF2 As String

   parF1 = "D:\test.xlsx"

   parF2 = "D:\test.csv"

    Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2
    Const adTypeText = 2

    Dim streamSrc, streamDst ' Source / Destination
    Set streamSrc = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    Set streamDst = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    streamDst.Type = adTypeText
    streamDst.Charset = "utf-8"
    streamDst.Open

    With streamSrc
        .Type = adTypeText
        .Charset = "Unicode" ' this is also the default value
        .Open
        .LoadFromFile parF1
        .copyTo streamDst
        .Close
    End With
    streamDst.saveToFile parF2, adSaveCreateOverWrite
    streamDst.Close
    Set streamSrc = Nothing
    Set streamDst = Nothing

End Sub
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try this: `ActiveWorkbook.WebOptions.Encoding = msoEncodingUTF8` and `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Book1.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV`

Comment: Perfect! This worked for me. Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 2):

If this is not working?

```
ActiveWorkbook.WebOptions.Encoding = msoEncodingUTF8
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Book1.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
```

Try this

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Book1.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSVUTF8
```

Comment: Only xlCSVUTF8 seems to work, but seems not supported in older excel version (before 2016), how is this possible? UTF-8 exists since long time